# Bibliography won't show alphabetically, if at all

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies

```
\documentclass[11pt,twoside]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{{images/}}
\usepackage[a4paper, width=150mm, top=25mm, bottom=25mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhead{}
\fancyhead[RO,LE]{Thesis Title}
\fancyfoot{}
\fancyfoot[LE,RO]{\thepage}
\fancyfoot[LO,CE]{Chapter\thechapter}
\fancyfoot[CO,RE]{Author Name}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.2pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.2pt}

\usepackage[backend=biber,style=alphabetic,sorting=ynt]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{references.bib}


\title{
    {Title}\\
    {\large University}\\
    {\includegraphics{graphics/1.png}}
}

\author{Name}
\date{May 2021}

\begin{document}

\maketitle
\tableofcontents

\chapter{Introduction}
\input{chapters/introduction}

\chapter{Chapter 1}
\input{chapters/chapter1}

\chapter{Chapter 2}
\input{chapters/chapter2}

\chapter{Chapter 3}
\input{chapters/chapter3}

\chapter{Conclusion}
\input{chapters/Conclusion}


\end{document}
```

Comment: Have you considered replacing `sorting=ynt` (year-name-title) with `sorting=nyt` (name-year-title)?

Comment: I was more looking for "alpha", which puts me to the next question, why I dont get why I write the title in my seperate bib file in big letter, and once compiled, it shows it in small letters in the Bibliography.

Comment: also, when I cite e.g. \cite{Chan 1996}, it wont let me, unless I write it like that \cite{chan1996} but it wouldn't show the full name of the author in the bibliography or in the text.

Comment: Please edit your posting to [minimum working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/5001).

Comment: As Mico says, `sorting=ynt` sorts by year first, then name, then title. If you are using `style=alphabetic,` it is usually better not to give any `sorting` option at all. `biblatex` automatically selects `sorting=anyt,` which is appropriate for that style. Unfortunately your other problem is much harder to diagnose. It is not clear to me what capital and small letters you are talking about. Note that entry keys in the `.bib` file may not contain spaces, so `Chan 1996` is not valid. `Chan1996` would be valid, but I usually prefer lowercase only, so `chan1996`. ...

Comment: ... The entry key is a purely internal label that should never appear in the output if everything goes well. The entry key will be shown in **bold** if the respective entry could not be found (there will also be a warning in that case).

Comment: To be more specific with my other problem:   "Transformation, and Challenge" is written in the bib file, after compiling it shows as "transformation,  and challenge" in the references.